# ClearCase find Command: Redirection to file doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, find, redirect, clearcase

Hallo.

I you use the following ClearCase Find Command in a Batch-File.

cleartool find . -version "version(\main\LATEST) && !lbtype(%3)" -print > y:...\%3.log

You see how the hits apper in the command window. It also creates the log-File, but it doesn't write the hits into it.

Thanks 
Kai

Answer (score 0):

The [redirect section of cleartool find examples](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425#redirect-output) does mention the kind of redirect you are using:

> 1. To get the STDOUT information add " `> file_name.txt`" to the end of the command string:
> 2. To get both STDOUT and STDERR information add " `> file_name.txt 2>&1`" to the end of the command string.

If you are sure your find command actually find and print some version, can you try and:

- capture both stdout and stderr (just to be sure)
- redirect to a simpler path (`c:\...`) to check if there is no side effect associated with the `Y:\...` path.

---

The [OP Kai Wissel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872412/kai-wissel) actually found the issue:

> The problem was the **`%3`** in "`version(\main\LATEST) && !lbtype(%3)`"
> That's my solution:

```
SET VERARG="version(\main\LATEST) && !lbtype(%3)" 
cleartool find . -version %VERARG% -print > C:\Test_Logs\%3.log
```

Comment: When I call the function directly from the command line, it works and it wrotes to the log-file. The problem only occurs in combination with the batch file.

Comment: @Kai: I understand, but am still curious to know if it happens for any path you use for the redirection.

Comment: I redirected it to several drives, but the problem don't disapper.

Comment: @Kai: ok, and that is also empty if you capture the stderr as well as stdout?

Comment: Yes, but i found the problem. The problem was the %3 in "version(\main\LATEST) && !lbtype(%3)" 

That's my solution: SET VERARG="version(\main\LATEST) && !lbtype(%3)" cleartool find . -version %VERARG% -print > C:\Test_Logs\%3.log

Comment: @Kai: excellent. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.